# InAppbrowser .close() not working in S4

Tags: cordova, twitter-oauth, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser, jsoauth

I am developing a Hybrid app using Cordova/PhoneGap.

While using Twitter login, browser do not close after navigating to success url.
This happens only in Samsung S4.

Code is something like this :

To open :

```
cb = window.open('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?' + data.text, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

To close :

```
cb.close();
```

There is no problem in S3.

Any solution or trick to resolve the same will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is may be due to the Android version (probably KitKat) and not the device itself. I have the same issue with a Nexus tablet. I will let you know If I find a fix.

Comment: I am testing on Galaxy S4 Jellybean.